# River boat round trip

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A river boat can travel at $20$ km per hour in still water.  The boat travels $30$ km upstream against the current 
          then turns around and travels the same distance back with the current.  If the total trip took $7.5$ hours, 
     what is the speed of the current? Solve this question algebraically as well as graphically.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What have you tried?  Here are some hints:  Name some variables.  Write down some equations in those variables that amount to distance $=$ rate $\times$ time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  if the current is $c$, the speed upstream is $20-c$ and downstream is $20+c$

Comment: :( that's all your goign to give me ahha?

Comment: @user73122:  do you have any thoughts on the problem?  It is much easier to give a useful answer if we see what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

$x=(v_{\rm still}-v_{\rm current})t_1$ (when it goes upstream)

$x=(v_{\rm still}+v_{\rm current})t_2$  (when it comes back downstream)

$t_1+t_2=7.5$

and solve for $v_{\rm current}$ , you know the rest of the variables.